# Hibernate Specification for Join

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data, criteria-api

I try to select the `Article` list by `Tag` which join by foreign key:

```
@Repository
public interface ArticleRepository extends JpaRepository<Article, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Article> {}

// Service call
public List<Article> findAllArticlesWithTag(String tag) {
    return articleRepository
            .findAll(articleSpecificationFactory.allArticlesWithTag(tag));
}
```

The problem in `Specification` factory method `allArticlesWithTag(String tag)`

```
public Specification<Article> allArticlesWithTag(String tag) {
        return new Specification<Article>() {
            @Override
            public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Article> root,
                                         CriteriaQuery<?> query,
                                         CriteriaBuilder builder) {
                Predicate predicate = builder.conjunction();
                if (Objects.nonNull(tag) && !tag.isBlank()) {
                    predicate.getExpressions().add(
                                 builder.in(builder.equal(root.get("tags"), tag))); // problem here
                }
                return predicate;
            }
        };
    }
```

How can I implement `toPredicate` for correct selection articles by tag?

SQL scheme:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS articles
(
    id      BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    title   VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tags
(
    article_id BIGINT REFERENCES articles (id),
    tag        VARCHAR(255)
);
```

But `Tag` entity no has its own java entity and represent as `@ElementCollection`:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "articles")
public class Article {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ElementCollection(targetClass = String.class,
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name = "tags",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "article_id"))
    @Column(name = "tag")
    private List<String> tags = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

I think it's should be a combination of `CriteriaBuilder builder` calls but how exactly? `builder.in(builder.equal(root.get("tags"), tag))` is wrong.

Comment: something like `builder.isMember(tag, root.get("tags"))`

Comment: @Andrey B. Panfilov yes, its work. thank you